# Many-to-many relationships delete object is very slow，How to make it faster?

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, many-to-many

CoreData Operation using https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

**I have 2 Tables,**

1. Playlist ， Column: PlaylistName
2. Tracks, Column: Album,Artist,CreateTime......

Playlist and Tracks is a many-to-many relationships , Delete Rule is Nullify.

**There are two situations:**

1. NSFetchedResultsController for 

   `[self MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"CreateTime" ascending:NO withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self inContext:context];
   ......
   Tracks *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   [obj MR_deleteEntity];
   [[obj managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];`

the delete Track Object quickly.

1. NSFetchedResultsController for 
   `[self MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"Album" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:nil ascending:NO delegate:self inContext:context];
   ......`

   *segue push*

`id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    AlbumTracksViewController *albumTracksvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    albumTracksvc.tracks =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sectionInfo objects]];
    albumTracksvc.title = [sectionInfo name];`

```
In AlbumTracksViewController：
```

`Tracks *obj = [self.tracks objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [obj MR_deleteEntity];
    [[obj managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];`

```
the delete Track Object very slow.
```

**What should I do to solve the problem of the delete slow?**

Comment: Profile to find what is slow. Is it really a deletion or a fetch? Use the core data instrument.

Comment: In the operation of the missile,Print the SQL view, CoreData is executed to 
CoreData: annotation: the to - many relationship fault "playlistTracks" for the objectID 0 x162f9e60 < x - CoreData: / / 56736401 - d5c E531-4-914 - c - C38EBA6EF3B2 / PlaylistEntity/p3 > fulfilled from the database. Got 9 rows, 
will block the longer time, so lead to slow

Comment: Profile with **Instruments**, it will do a much better job of telling you where the code is slowing down.